# How to make Android Studio STOP generating local.properties?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have set an environment variable `ANDROID_HOME`, which points to my android SDK location. However, every time I open my project in Android Studio it places `local.properties` file to the root of my project and copies my SDK location from `ANDROID_HOME` to this file. I want Android Studio use `ANDROID_HOME` directly, without generating `local.properties`.

Why? I'm on Windows 10 and I use Bash for Windows. I want to run command line using Bash while running Android Studio from Windows. For this I need two `ANDROID_HOME` environment variables, one for Windows, one for Bash. This is because although they point to the same (windows) android SDK the format is different, for Windows it is `C:\Users\me\Android SDK` while for Bash it's `/mnt/c/Users/me/Android SDK`. When Android Studio creates `local.properties` with windows path Bash becomes broken since apparently `local.properties` takes advantage over `ANDROID_HOME`, so I have to delete it manually.

Comment: Have you tried having just an empty `local.properties` file?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, it diligently puts `sdk.dir` line back...

Answer (score 1):

You *might* find this article useful:

[Posix path conversion (mingw.org)](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion)

The gradle android plugin "Application" extension
(your regular gradle-android interface) has a [property
sdkDirectory](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.html#com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension:sdkDirectory). Perhaps this can override it? I can't check.

I think there is a configuration switch for bash on Windows to parse path separators Windows-like, can't seem to find it, it is buried deep inside MinGW or MSYS docs I think.

Last resort - git Hooks. Read the [ProGit book](https://github.com/progit/progit2/releases/download/2.1.116/progit.pdf) chapter on Hooks.

Answer (score 0):

The Android will generate this file always when gradle sync it. But if you delete it and define ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_NDK_HOME environment variables, every time that generates it will read ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_NDK_HOME.

If you want to build your project in many computers with different home folders, just keep the local.properties outside the source version control.